# MySQL NOT IN not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these queries:

```
select * from indicators_values WHERE indicator_id=3255;

select * from indicators WHERE indicator_id=3255;

select * from indicators where indicator_id not in (select indicator_id from indicators_values);
```

So, I don't have any rows as result of first query. I have one result as result of the second query. The problem is the third query. I don't have any results in the third query, and there should be one! Do you know what can be the error here?

Comment: very strange ... :/     Check the database where these query works if you launch them separately in different shell

Comment: I don't understand your comment @BUcorp

Comment: it's impossible getting this results unless you are working in different database for third query. or you can change your third query as follow to check : select * from indicators where indicator_id not in (select indicator_id from indicators_values where indicator_id is not null);

Comment: Well, I have used also MySQL for many many years, and I also think it is impossible :) but it is possible!.......

Comment: did you try the query i mention ?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want your question not to be downvoted or closed. This way it is hard to say what's going on

Comment: Ok, I did. But I still don't understand why the first one didn't work.

Comment: does it work this now?

Comment: This is as clear as it gets, I think. Not sure how I can improve it.

Comment: It appears in the result set now! I don't know why this happens......

Comment: i also figured (rarely) this problem in some mysql older versions where there is null in the set.. This might be the only reason

Comment: Ah ok, so it is the shitty old version of MySQL that we are using.

Comment: which one is it?..i suppose >= 5.7.1 is working quite good

Comment: I is version 5.6.36

Comment: I've tested on MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.3 ... unfortunately this happen as well

Comment: mysql 8 in my opinion it's another workinprogress version , i'm using 5.7.17 and this seem stable

Comment: always glad to help mysqellers :D

Comment: Ahah, thanks anyway. APparently here it is very difficult to change a version of Mysql :).......so I'm stuck with it. But at least you helped me with this workaround, thanks very much for that! :) Please post an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: i experienced these kind of problems years ago but i still doing condition like this in some application because of these versions problem so unfortunately it's the only way in real environment application where you cannot change resources as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

version problem

try

```
select * from indicators where indicator_id not in (select indicator_id from indicators_values where indicator_id is not null);
```